# Why long table doesn't go to the next page in latex

Tags: latex

I need to create a long table in latex, but when the size of the table is longer than page, the table doesn't go to the next page. For example, I need the table to be gone to the next page automatically regardless the size of the table.  Here is the code I need to write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim} % multi line comment pkg
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{cases}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} 


    % allow line breaking, suppress full justfication

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llll}
aa & \multicolumn{2}{l}{ewee}                  &     \\
bb  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                    &     \\
ccc  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}               &     \\
ddd  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                                  &     \\
eee  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                            &     \\
fff  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                      &     \\
rrr  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                      &     \\
fff  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                     &     \\
rere  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                     &     \\
rere & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}     &     \\
wqwq & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                 &     \\
trt  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                           &     \\
yyt   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                                   &     \\
tre  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                        &     \\
hgh  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                        &     \\
wqw  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                                &     \\
iui  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                        &     \\
rer   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{utjh}                            &     \\
wqw   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                               &     \\
lkj   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                                   &     \\
lkj   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                             &     \\
ewe   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                                &     \\
hng  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                     &     \\
fdf & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                       &     \\
dgf & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}            &     \\
gfdfd   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                             &     \\
dsd   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text text text}                                    &     \\
fdf  & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text text text text}                         \\
hghg  & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text text text text}                           \\
fgf   & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text text text text}                                        \\
lkl  & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text text text text}                             \\
BPSK & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text text text text}                            \\
LRE  & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text text text text}                                 \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just you can copy from the table and past to see that when the table is longer than page length, it doesn't open new page. . .

Comment: Normal `tabular` environment can't break across pages. If you want page breaks, have a look at the `longtable` package https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable . Also packages to create lists of acronyms will automatically allow page breaks if that's what you are trying to do with the table.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am newbie in latex, could you please modify my above code to be used with `longtable` and put your reply as answer to close the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `longtable` package to create a table that will automatically break across pages. You need to

- replace `tabular` with `longtable`
- remove the `table` environment around it

Furthermore avoid the excessive use of `\multicolumn`. I know these nasty online table generators will add it everywhere, but it can interfere with the alignment of the cell contents, so only use it when appropriate.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

%\begin{table}[]
\begin{longtable}{llll}
aa & ewee \\
bb & text text text text \\
ccc & text text text text \\
ddd & text text text text \\
eee & text text text text \\
fff & text text text text \\
rrr & text text text text \\
fff & text text text text \\
rere & text text text text \\
rere & text text text text \\
wqwq & text text text text \\
trt & text text text text \\
yyt & text text text text \\
tre & text text text text \\
hgh & text text text text \\
wqw & text text text text \\
iui & text text text text \\
rer & utjh \\
wqw & text text text text \\
lkj & text text text text \\
lkj & text text text text \\
ewe & text text text text \\
hng & text text text text \\
fdf & text text text text \\
dgf & text text text text \\
gfdfd & text text text text \\
dsd & text text text text \\
fdf & text text text text \\
hghg & text text text text \\
fgf & text text text text \\
lkl & text text text text \\
BPSK & text text text text \\
LRE & text text text text \\
aa & ewee \\
bb & text text text text \\
ccc & text text text text \\
ddd & text text text text \\
eee & text text text text \\
fff & text text text text \\
rrr & text text text text \\
fff & text text text text \\
rere & text text text text \\
rere & text text text text \\
wqwq & text text text text \\
trt & text text text text \\
yyt & text text text text \\
tre & text text text text \\
hgh & text text text text \\
wqw & text text text text \\
iui & text text text text \\
rer & utjh \\
wqw & text text text text \\
lkj & text text text text \\
lkj & text text text text \\
ewe & text text text text \\
hng & text text text text \\
fdf & text text text text \\
dgf & text text text text \\
gfdfd & text text text text \\
dsd & text text text text \\
fdf & text text text text \\
hghg & text text text text \\
fgf & text text text text \\
lkl & text text text text \\
BPSK & text text text text \\
LRE & text text text text \\
\end{longtable}
%\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you .. but why the table is centered,  I need it to be left side.

Comment: @New_student Centred is the default alignment for a longtable, but you can get it to the left side with `\begin{longtable}[l]{llll}`

Comment: +1: Stupid question: The code defines `\newcolumntype{L}` but later use `\begin{longtable}{llll}`. Is this on purpose or a leftover from the MWE?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner That's just a leftover from the MWE in the question

Comment: Where do my `caption` and `label` commands go after I remove the `table` environment?

Comment: @user2023370 See page 10 of the user guide for an example with caption and label